# last button in layout doesn't have elevation

Tags: android, xml, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm working with Android Lollipop.
I have this layout:

```
    <LinearLayout
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:id="@+id/buttonlayout"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing_normal"
       android:orientation="vertical" >

      <Button
         android:id="@+id/facebook_button"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         style="@style/FacebookButton" />

     <com.myCompany.views.widgets.CustomTextView
        android:id="@+id/or_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_normal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_normal"
        android:text="@string/app.widget.connexion.or"
        app:font_name="Roboto-Medium.ttf" />

     <Button
        android:id="@+id/myCompany_button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/myCompanyButton" />
```

the two style applied to the buttons are simply ripple effect with different background colors. The thing is the first button has an elevation with a shadow when we click it and the second hasn't unless I add an other widget below him. I suppose it's due to the ripple effect and because I had to change the background attribute, but I don't know how to make the effect back.
I tried to use translationZ and elevation attribute, but it didn't work (or I failed to use them properly).

any ideas ?

Comment: Let some space under the button. It sounds like the elevation is cut off.

Comment: Oh, yeah.. I just add some margin and it works fine... thanks !